# Missing .bash_profile and .bashrc files

Tags: command-line, macos, bash

I don't have `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` files and I am definitely using the bash shell. I am using Mac OS X 10.11.1 El Capitan.

How do I permanently modify my `$PATH` to cut down the default values Apple ships?

Comment: What have you tried - have you tried creating a .bash_profile and .bashrc (note no _)

Comment: No I haven't. My $PATH variable is set, though. Where is it getting those settings from? I need to remove something from it.

Comment: That is a different question - and has been asked many times

Comment: @Mark link please?

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily a duplicate of the linked question. I flagged the answer as unclear and the OP should specify what exactly to remove because there are a lot of different methods to add (and remove) paths to (or from) $PATH.

Comment: @Mark that only changes it for the session, not permanently. I need to know the location where these path variables come from because they are pointing to places that no longer exist.

Comment: @Dan, see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files -- there are "global" config files that get sourced.

Comment: Thank you @glennjackman that link solved my issue: "When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable."

Comment: It was in `~/.profile` which I didn't know existed nor to look for. Most tutorials online asking to modify $PATH never mention this file, only the previous two. Thank you.

Comment: @Dan Well done with the edits. I've nuked most of the temporary comments. Cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` do not have to exist for `$PATH` to work, they're for bash configuration. According to [the bash docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files),

> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

- To add a path to your `$PATH` variable for a single terminal session, do so as follows: `export PATH=$PATH:pathToYourDirectory`, for multiple directories `export PATH=$PATH:pathToYourFirstDirectory:pathToYourSecondDirectory` ...
- To see what's in your `$PATH`: `echo $PATH` or `cat /etc/paths`
- `/etc/paths` is the file that holds your system path variables

Run `man path_helper` for more information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31648/discussion-between-maetsoh-and-dan).